# su コマンドの "-" オプションの説明が日本語と英語で少し異なる理由

Tags: ubuntu

`su`コマンドの`-`オプションの説明が日本語だと

> > オプション引数 - を用いると、直接ログインした場合と同じ環境に初期化される。

なのに対し、英語だと

> > The optional argument - may be used to provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.

と"同じ"ではなく"似ている"という表現になっています。
特に困ってはいないのですが、どちらの表現が正しいのでしょうか？

おそらく英語の方が正しい気がするんですが、
だとしたら直接ログインした場合との違いを知りたいです。

環境は`Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`で`su`コマンドはバージョンを表示する方法がわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ubuntu でなくて hpux の場合ですが

`root` で ssh login した場合
`USER` 環境変数が設定されている `USER=root`
`MAIL` 環境変数が設定されている `MAIL=/var/mail/root`
`SSH` 系環境変数が設定されている `SSH_CONNECTION` や `SSH_CLIENT`

一般ユーザで ssh login した後 `su -` した場合
`USER` 環境変数が消失している
`MAIL` 環境変数が消失している
`SSH` 系環境変数が消失している

という違いがありました。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。環境変数に差が出るかもしれないんですね。もう少し調べてみた所`su -`では`.login`が読み込まれず`sudo -i`では`/etc/profile`が読み込まれないために違いが生まれてそうだとわかりました。ディストリごとの違いについてはわからないままなのですが…。 http://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used

Answer (score 4):

回答しようと思ったら解決されちゃってましたが、一応。

[JMProject](http://linuxjm.osdn.jp/)でsuを検索したら、[3件見つかりました。](http://linuxjm.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/man.cgi?Pagename=su&submit=Search%21&Sec1=on&Sec2=on&Sec3=on&Sec4=on&Sec5=on&Sec6=on&Sec7=on&Sec8=on)

GNUのmanのほうには、もうちょっと詳しく書かれていますね。

> -, -l, --login
>       シェルをログインシェルにする。すなわち以下のような取り扱いをする: すべての環境変数を解除する。その上で `TERM'、 `HOME'、 `SHELL' を前述 のように設定し、 `USER'、 `LOGNAME' （スーパーユーザーであっても）を同 じく前述のように設定する。続いて `PATH' をコンパイル時のデフォルト値に 設定する。ディレクトリを user のホームディレクトリに変更する。シェル名の前に `-' を付加し、シェルに ログイン時のスタートアップファイルを読ませる。

以下個人的見解ですが、suコマンドとしてはシェルにオプション渡しているだけで、具体的な環境設定はシェルの仕事になるので、明言を避けているだけ、だと思いますが、どうでしょうかねぇ。

Comment: 日本語訳でもGNUとshadowというのに別れてるんですね、初めて知りました。何か躓いた時に具体的な動作を参照したい時はこちらで確認することにします。